Normality of the intersection between a Carter subgroup and the nilpotent residual of a solvable group G
In his book "Group Theory," Schenkman, in the proof of Theorem VII.4.a, states that in a finite solvable group $G$, the intersection of a Carter subgroup $C$ (i.e., a self-normalizing and nilpotent subgroup) and the nilpotent residual $N$ (i.e., the smallest normal subgroup $M$ such that the quotient $G/M$ is nilpotent) is normal in $G$. How can we prove this claim that Schenkman presents as if it were obvious without proof? If it may help, in the same theorem it is shown, quite easily, that $G=NC$.

I don't know much about the theory of Carter subgroups, but I don't think I believe this. A possible counterexample is a split extension $G=3^3:S_4$ of an irreducible module of dimension $3$ over ${\mathbb F}_3$ for $S_4$ by $S_4$. Then (I think) a Carter subgroup $C$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup, a dihedral group of order $8$, which is indeed self-normalizing in $G$.  The nilpotent residual $N$ is the subgroup $3^3:A_4$ of index $2$ in $G$, and $N \cap C$ has order $4$ and is not normal in $G$.

The theorem pointed to certainly does not say what you claim it says.

@Dave Benson It's not in the statement of the theorem. But he uses it to prove point 4, the last one. And it doesn't look like it comes from other assumptions he made during the proof, but he affirms it like it's true in general. Maybe i'm not totally understanding the proof.

@DerekHolt I know that Sylow $2$-subgroup of $S_4$ are self-normalizing, but how do you see that it is also self-normalizing in $G$? Is it because the module is irreducible? Also why the nilpotent residual is $3^3:A_4$? Thanks in advance.

Another counterexample: fix a finite field $F$ with $>2$ elements and consider the subgroup $G$ consisting of upper triangular $4\times 4$ matrices $(a_{ij})$ such that $a_{11}=a_{22}$. Write this group as $DU$ ($D$ the diagonal matrices, $U$ the upper unipotent matrices). The centralizer $V$ of $D$ in $U$ consists of those matrices of the form $e_{12}(x)$. We see that $DV$ is a Carter subgroup, and $DV\cap U=V$. But $V$ is not normal. This counterexample is inspired by the obvious Lie algebra analogue (which yields a counterexample too — in this case we say "Cartan subalgebra", not "Carter").

@YCor The unipotent matrices $U$ are a nilpotent subgroup, but why are they, in this case, the nilpotent residual of $G=DU$?

@AlessandroGiorgi It's not, sorry. I should have defined $G$ with the condition $a_{11}=a_{33}$ (not $=a_{22}$). Then, with this corrected definition, it's OK (with $V$ redefined as the set of matrices $e_{13}(x)$). The reason is that the action of $D$ on the abelianization of $U$ has no fixed point, so $[D,U]=U$.

@YCor So are you using the fact that, in general, the nilpotent residual $N$ it's the product of all the normal subgroups $M$ such that $[G,M]=M$? In the counterxample is $U$ the only normal subgroup with this property? Sorry for so many question but i'm trying to really understand.

This is true, although I would rather reformulate as: a normal $N$ subgroup of $G$ is the nilpotent residual iff $[G,N]=N$ and $G/N$ is nilpotent. (Of course in this case there are other irrelevant smaller normal subgroups $W$ satisfying $[G,W]=W$.)

@YCor Ok thanks a lot. I have to reread the counterexample, but if everything works then it means i must be missing something in the proof of Schenkman.

I confirmed all of my claimed properties of the counterexample with a computer calculation in Magma.

@DerekHolt Ok thank you. I'm still trying to figure out what is going on in Schenkman's proof and why he claims that the intersection is normal.

I don't have access to the book, and Derek's counterexample is certainly correct, but it is true in general that if $C$ is a Carter subgroup of a (finite) solvable group $G$ and $N$ is any normal subgroup of $G$, then $C$ is also a Carter subgroup of $N_{G}(C \cap N),$ so sometimes in inductive proof about Carter subgroups you can reduce to the case that $C \cap N$ is normal in $G$ for every normal subgroup $N$ of $G$.

@GeoffRobinson Yes this could be it, the proof is indeed by induction. Still it's a bit strange because  he never mentions the reduction to $N_{G}(C \cap N)$ (even if this is not uncommon), and there should be a part where he proves that if the "property" it's true in $N_{G}(C \cap N)$ then it is also in $G$, but there is none of this. Thanks anyway

I am only mentioning that general fact as it seems possibly relevant, but it speculative, as I can't see the book at present. If that is what he was doing, you might expect a statement such as "we may suppose that $C \cap N$ is normal in G".

@GeoffRobinson Yeah i agree it may be relevant. It's a relatively long proof so the reason why $C \cap N$ is normal in $G$ might be "hidden" in some previous step; but then there are other more intuitive statements that he cares to specify. That's why i find it weird. I could put a link to the book, but i don't know if it's an ok thing to do.

It's OK, no need to send a link. Maybe some of the other commenters who have the text available can help you.
